# group, sum and join combined in sql

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I've got a table `spending`, which contains some basic fields which define the item of purchase, the time of purchase, and the value of purchase, and which account they were purchased from: `spItem`, `spAmount`, `spDate` and `spAccount`.

I have made a query to group them per month, one Account at a time, which works fine:

```
SELECT YEAR(spDate) as spYear,
       MONTH(spDate) as spMonth,
       SUM(spAmount) AS TotalAmount
FROM spending
WHERE spAccount like 'Bank1'
GROUP BY YEAR(spDate), MONTH(spDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(spDate), MONTH(spDate)
```

and

```
SELECT YEAR(spDate) as spYear,
       MONTH(spDate) as spMonth,
       SUM(spAmount) AS TotalAmount
FROM spending
WHERE spAccount like 'Bank2'
GROUP BY YEAR(spDate), MONTH(spDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(spDate), MONTH(spDate)
```

I'm trying to get one table which could combine both queries, and display `Bank1` into one column and `Bank2` into the next column. There may be some months where one of the Accounts has no spending. In this case it should show a zero value and not just skip it.

Anyone that can point me in the right way will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do a select on the date with year and month combined as one field that will sort and group accordingly. Also make sure to group on account first, as the order of grouping in SQL matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(spDate) as spYear, MONTH(spDate) as spMonth, SUM(spAmount) AS TotalAmount,(SELECT SUM(spAmount) AS TotalAmount2 FROM spending WHERE spAccount like 'Bank2' GROUP BY YEAR(spDate), MONTH(spDate) ORDER BY YEAR(spDate), MONTH(spDate)) FROM spending WHERE spAccount like 'Bank1' GROUP BY YEAR(spDate), MONTH(spDate) ORDER BY YEAR(spDate), MONTH(spDate)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to run the query but got the following statement: "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field."

Comment: Thanks :) now a pop-up says "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly :-)

For each available month and year (where data exists in at least one of the accounts) show the SUM of each of the accounts (even if one of them is 0).
To do this I JOINED the 2 queries and used the ISNULL function to get the data from the correct source.

Here is my solution with dummy data:

```
--Preparing Dummy Data
;WITH spending
 AS (SELECT '01-01-2010' spDate, 
            100          spamount, 
            'Bank1'      spaccount 
     UNION 
     SELECT '01-01-2010' spDate, 
            200          spamount, 
            'Bank1'      spaccount 
     UNION 
     SELECT '03-01-2010' spDate, 
            150          spamount, 
            'Bank1'      spaccount 
     UNION 
     SELECT '04-01-2010' spDate, 
            500          spamount, 
            'Bank1'      spaccount 
     UNION 
     SELECT '01-01-2010' spDate, 
            200          spamount, 
            'Bank1'      spaccount 
     UNION 
     SELECT '03-01-2010' spDate, 
            10           spamount, 
            'Bank2'      spaccount 
     UNION 
     SELECT '05-01-2010' spDate, 
            800          spamount, 
            'Bank2'      spaccount 
     UNION 
     SELECT '03-01-2010' spDate, 
            110          spamount, 
            'Bank2'      spaccount 
     UNION 
     SELECT '01-01-2010' spDate, 
            100          spamount, 
            'Bank2'      spaccount) 
--End of Dummy Data

--Start Query on Dummy Data
SELECT ISNULL(Bank1.SPMONTH, Bank2.SPMONTH) AS spMonth, 
       ISNULL(Bank1.SPYEAR, Bank2.SPYEAR)   AS spYear, 
       ISNULL(Bank1.TOTALAMOUNT, 0)         AS TotalAmount_Bank1, 
       ISNULL(Bank2.TOTALAMOUNT, 0)         AS TotalAmount_Bank2 
FROM   (SELECT YEAR(SPDATE)  AS spYear, 
               MONTH(SPDATE) AS spMonth, 
               SUM(SPAMOUNT) AS TotalAmount 
        FROM   spending 
        WHERE  SPACCOUNT LIKE 'Bank1' 
        GROUP  BY YEAR(SPDATE), 
                  MONTH(SPDATE)) AS Bank1 
       FULL JOIN (SELECT YEAR(SPDATE)  AS spYear, 
                         MONTH(SPDATE) AS spMonth, 
                         SUM(SPAMOUNT) AS TotalAmount 
                  FROM   spending 
                  WHERE  SPACCOUNT LIKE 'Bank2' 
                  GROUP  BY YEAR(SPDATE), 
                            MONTH(SPDATE)) AS Bank2 
              ON Bank1.SPMONTH = Bank2.SPMONTH 
                 AND Bank2.SPYEAR = Bank2.SPYEAR 
ORDER  BY SPYEAR, 
          SPMONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use grouping with conditional aggregating to get totals for both accounts in one query. Here's what it would look like:

```
SELECT YEAR(spDate) as spYear,
       MONTH(spDate) as spMonth,
       SUM(CASE spAccount WHEN 'Bank1' THEN spAmount ELSE 0 END) AS Bank1,
       SUM(CASE spAccount WHEN 'Bank2' THEN spAmount ELSE 0 END) AS Bank2
FROM spending
WHERE spAccount IN ('Bank1', 'Bank2')
GROUP BY YEAR(spDate), MONTH(spDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(spDate), MONTH(spDate)
;
```